# Parse request body with custom content-type to json in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using play to proxy my API calls from the ui. For example POST:

```
def post(url: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    Async {
      WS.url(proxyUrl + request.uri)
        .withQueryString(request.queryString.mapValues(_.head).toSeq: _*)
        .withHeaders(request.headers.toMap.mapValues(_.head).toSeq: _*)
        .post(request.body.asJson).map(response => Ok(response.body))
    }
}
```

but this can only handle "application/json" and "text/json" content types. But now I want to make requests with custom content type: "application/vnd.MyCustomType-v1+json;charset=utf-8" and of course it doesn't work with current implementation. Have tried different solutions, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
I'm using play 2.1

Comment: I don't quite understand your question and why it "doesn't work". You should just be able to do: `WS.url(...).withHeaders(HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/vnd.MyCustomType-v1+json;charset=utf-8" )`

Comment: The problem is that incoming request.body cannot be parsed into json. Error message: [Expecting text/json or application/json body]

Answer (score 1):

The source for the json body parser looks like this:

```
def json(maxLength: Int): BodyParser[JsValue] = when(
  _.contentType.exists(m => m.equalsIgnoreCase("text/json") || m.equalsIgnoreCase("application/json")),
  tolerantJson(maxLength),
  createBadResult("Expecting text/json or application/json body")
)
```

`tolerantJson` is, itself, a body parser that does the json parsing without a check of the content-type header, so you should just be able to use that to parse your request instead of `parse.json`.

If you want to go further and have a parser that checks your specific `content-type` header then you could use

```
when(
  _.contentType.exists(m => m.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedContentType)),
  tolerantJson(maxLength),
  createBadResult("Wrong content type")
)
```

to create your own parser.